# What to do if apt-get -f install fails?

Tags: debian, apt, polkit

I'm in a difficult situation.

Using Debian Jessie / Stretch, `apt-get -f install` fails.

The system is effectively stuck. I've sshed in now. As far as login terminals, only one was becoming available. (Namely, only alt-ctrl-F1 brought up a login terminal on the actual machine, alt-ctrl-f[2-5] failed).

It seems to be related to the bug listed [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit-1/+bug/1447654). Though there are multiple problems: krb-kdc doesn't unpack because PolicyKit timeout was reached `(g-io-error-quark, 24)`, then errors unpacking krb5-admin-server, the an error message that LDAP must be enabled (though it is and connects fine).

Namely, there are multiple time-outs with apt-get (to PolicyKit bits it seems). As far as the network, I've set the timeout time to 1200, with no seeming effect. 
The full error message:

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  krb5-admin-server krb5-kdc
Suggested packages:
  openbsd-inetd inet-superserver krb5-kdc-ldap
The following packages will be upgraded:
  krb5-admin-server krb5-kdc
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 73 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/320 kB of archives.
After this operation, 115 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Reading changelogs... Done
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 296869 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../krb5-kdc_1.13.2+dfsg-2_amd64.deb ...
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
Failed to execute operation: Connection timed out
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
Failed to stop krb5-kdc.service: Connection timed out
Failed to get load state of krb5-kdc.service: Connection timed out
invoke-rc.d: initscript krb5-kdc, action "stop" failed.
failed to stop krb5-kdc
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
Failed to execute operation: Connection timed out
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
Failed to stop krb5-kdc.service: Connection timed out
Failed to get load state of krb5-kdc.service: Connection timed out
invoke-rc.d: initscript krb5-kdc, action "stop" failed.
failed to stop krb5-kdc
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/krb5-kdc_1.13.2+dfsg-2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
Failed to execute operation: Connection timed out
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
Failed to execute operation: Connection timed out
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
Failed to start krb5-kdc.service: Connection timed out
invoke-rc.d: initscript krb5-kdc, action "start" failed.
Preparing to unpack .../krb5-admin-server_1.13.2+dfsg-2_amd64.deb ...
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
Failed to execute operation: Connection timed out
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
Failed to stop krb5-admin-server.service: Connection timed out
Failed to get load state of krb5-admin-server.service: Connection timed out
invoke-rc.d: initscript krb5-admin-server, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
Failed to execute operation: Connection timed out
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Activation of org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 timed out (g-dbus-error-quark, 20)
Failed to stop krb5-admin-server.service: Connection timed out
Failed to get load state of krb5-admin-server.service: Connection timed out
invoke-rc.d: initscript krb5-admin-server, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/krb5-admin-server_1.13.2+dfsg-2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
insserv: Service ldap has to be enabled to start service krb5-admin-server
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/krb5-kdc_1.13.2+dfsg-2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/krb5-admin-server_1.13.2+dfsg-2_amd64.deb
Error: Timeout was reached
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Questions:

1. What else can I do to force `apt-get -f install`?
2. Would it help to force a roll-back to Jessie?

Comment: (Simple mentioning: alt/ctrl/f1 doesn't get you a virtual terminal, but a real. The virtual terminal is what belongs to, f.e. a remote ssh session, i.e. there is no hardware character device behind it.)

Comment: I don't think `apt-get` is the issue, and PolicyKit doesn't involve the network (at least, the Internet network). If you run `systemctl status`, are there any failed jobs that might explain the error?

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that PolKit was a network issue. The collocation was in hopes to elicit a way to increase timeout or ignore polkit failures.
systemctl tells me there are "3 units" failed but I don't see what they are. It's probably kerberos / LDAP, procps related. krb5-admin-server is attempting to start but says LDAP must be enabled - LDAP is running - not sure what it wants. As far as procps, it says it's in a "very bad inconsistent state"

Comment: well, I've kludged away at a few prerm and postinst scripts (to exit 0). Now I'm pretty much left with the "Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
Failed to execute operation: Connection timed out" problem.