# Postfix install error

Tags: apt, postfix

I was running `mc` and tried to install curl and postfix in the shell: `apt-get install curl postfix`. A configuration dialog for postfix appeared and after pressing Ctrl-o (Toggle show/hide MC) two times I couldn't read the configuration message anymore so I quit MC with F10. The apt-get process still existed and I killed it with `sudo kill xxxx`.
Now apt-get doesn't work.

I've tried `apt-get -f install`

```
X@X ~ % LC_ALL=C sudo apt-get -f install                   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  exim4-config lsb-invalid-mta
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  postfix
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  exim4-config lsb-invalid-mta
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 1 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/523 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2462 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: postfix: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 lsb-core depends on lsb-invalid-mta (>= 4.1+Debian13+nmu1) | mail-transport-agent; however:
  Package lsb-invalid-mta is not installed.
  Package mail-transport-agent is not installed.
  Package postfix which provides mail-transport-agent is to be removed.
  Package exim4-daemon-light which provides mail-transport-agent is not installed.
 bsd-mailx depends on default-mta | mail-transport-agent; however:
  Package default-mta is not installed.
  Package exim4-daemon-light which provides default-mta is not installed.
  Package mail-transport-agent is not installed.
  Package postfix which provides mail-transport-agent is to be removed.
  Package exim4-daemon-light which provides mail-transport-agent is not installed.

(Reading database ... 421170 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing postfix (2.11.3-1) ...
dpkg: error processing package postfix (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 102
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postfix
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and other solutions presented in various questions ([Q1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/398120/fix-dependency-when-apt-get-f-install-fails), [Q2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229244/what-to-do-if-apt-get-f-install-fails), [Q3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/383804/dpkg-package-is-in-a-very-bad-inconsistent-state-how-to-fix-it)): `apt-get purge postfix`, `apt-get --reinstall install postfix`, `dpkg --pending --configure`.

A really similar question (duplicate?) is [Error in postfix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727182/error-in-postfix), but it has no answer.

How can I fix the package manager? My OS is Debian Jessie.

**EDIT 1**
Bahamut's suggestions fails with error code 102:

```
X@X ~ % LC_ALL=C sudo dpkg --install /var/cache/apt/archives/postfix_2.11.3-1_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package postfix.
(Reading database ... 421172 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../postfix_2.11.3-1_amd64.deb ...
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 102
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
dpkg: ... it looks like that went OK
Unpacking postfix (2.11.3-1) over (2.11.3-1) ...
Setting up postfix (2.11.3-1) ...
insserv: script postfix is not an executable regular file, skipped!

Postfix configuration was not changed.  If you need to make changes, edit
/etc/postfix/main.cf (and others) as needed.  To view Postfix configuration
values, see postconf(1).

After modifying main.cf, be sure to run '/etc/init.d/postfix reload'.

Running newaliases
dpkg: error processing package postfix (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 102
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u5) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.33-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u6) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postfix
```

Comment: You might get more answers if your command output would be in English: `LC_ALL=C sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: @JakobLenfers I didn't knew about it. Question updated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Manually removing configuration files worked:

```
rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/postfix.*
apt-get purge postfix
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `dpkg --install /var/cache/apt/archives/postfix_2.11.3-1_amd64.deb` and after `apt -f install`

Comment: I think a bit more of explanation why this could solve the problem is in order.

Comment: Doesn't work, see edit.